# Unable to change radio button css styling on check

Tags: css, reactjs, styled-components

[image]

Unable to check inside circle style. 
It should be smaller than the outside border circle when checked.

```
   export const RadioWrapper = styled.input`
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    &:checked{
      background-color: #000000;
      border: .3px solid #000000; 
      transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    }
    `;
```

Comment: please create snippet, So we could be help you. :)

Comment: Check the image added above

Comment: Try to "transform: scale(0.8);" on :checked

Comment: It makes the entire radio button small on check

Comment: I need full code of your button, Please create snippet, codepen or something else so we could be help you. :)

Comment: <BrInput type="radio" id="faNum" value="faNum" onChange={this.handleRadioSelect} checked={faRrLabel === 'faNum' ? true : false} />

Comment: you can use `after` `before` for this.

Comment: The best way to achive this is only with after before elements and css

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pseudo element for the checked state:

```
&:checked{
  &:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      margin: auto;
      background-color: #000000;
  }
}
```

Remember to add `position: relative` to the button so that the inside smaller circle is positioned at the center of it.

Answer (score 0):

You have one tiny error. You should add `.attrs({ type: 'checkbox' })` to define that you're creating checkbox and not ordinary input

```
export const RadioWrapper = styled.input.attrs({ type: 'checkbox' })`
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 26px;
  height: 26px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  margin-right: 50px;
  background-color: transparent;
  outline: none;
  appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  &:checked{
      background-color: #000000;
      border: .3px solid #000000; 
      transition: background .15s, box-shadow .1s; 
    }
`;
```

And [working sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/styledcheckbox-vy8j3)

And here is useful [docs](https://medium.com/@colebemis/building-a-checkbox-component-with-react-and-styled-components-8d3aa1d826dd) with details

Answer (score 0):

You can use after before this way

```
input {
border-radius: 50%;
width: 26px;
height: 26px;
border: 1px solid #000000;
margin-right: 50px;
background-color: transparent;
outline: none;
appearance:none;
-moz-appearance: none;
-webkit-appearance: none;    
position: relative;
&:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: background .15s; 
}
&:checked{
  &:before {
    background-color: #000000;      
  }
}
```

}

Check this pen https://codepen.io/shubhanu-sharma/pen/PooMjvb.

```css
input {
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 26px;
    height: 26px;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    margin-right: 50px;
    background-color: transparent;
    outline: none;
    appearance:none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;    
    position: relative;   
}

input:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 2px;
  right: 2px;
  bottom: 2px;
  left: 2px;
  border-radius: 100%;
  transition: background .15s; 
}

input:checked:before{
  background-color: #000000;      
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" />
```